# missing symbol from libroscpp.so?

Tags: ros, libroscpp, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I built a ROS package in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and ROS Indigo and now I test these executables that I built in different Linux and ROS distributions.
Giving an example, when I setup a VM with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Hydro everything worked fine.

Now I am trying to run my package in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS Kinetic and I am getting this error:

```
maria@maria-VirtualBox:~/devel/lib/execDir$ ./executableName 
./executableName: symbol lookup error: ./executableName: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros4initERiPPcRKSsj
```

and when I filter the symbol:

```
maria@maria-VirtualBox:~/devel/lib/execDir$ echo _ZN3ros4initERiPPcRKSsj|c++filt
ros::init(int&, char**, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)
```

Also If i search for this symbol in libroscpp.so in ROS Indigo I can find it, but in Kinetic I do not!

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242991/missing-symbol-from-libroscpp.so?/) by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-02**:
Are you actually *compiling* on Ubuntu version X, then trying to run the *same binaries* on Ubuntu version Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not guarantee ABI compatibility between major versions, and neither does Ubuntu. The ROS developers do their best to make sure that there aren't ABI changes within patch releases for a particular version of ROS, but sometimes they slip through testing too.

I don't expect your experiment to work, and I'm not surprised that it doesn't.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2